# Set property in treeview.selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf, object, treeview

I have a WPF treeview that displays multiple nested classes based on hierarchical datatemplates. It uses the classes here: https://complexdatatemplates.codeplex.com/. This question applies to DataGrids also, though or any control who's selected item is an anonymous class.

What I want to do seems simple. I want to select an item, then press a button and operate directly on the selected item--not the SelectedItem property of the tree view, but the object behind it. But, since the compiler doesn't know the class of the selected item until runtime, it understandably won't give me access to any of the methods or properties in it.

The class in this case is 'Roms', the treeview is 'DB_tree'. I can create a new object from the selected item, and cast it as Roms, then do whatever I want. Like this

```
roms = (Roms)DB_tree.SelectedItem;
```

But I can't figure out how to operate on the actual object that would be returned by DB_tree.SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that by assigning `(Roms)DB_tree.SelectedItem` to another object

```
DummyObject = (Roms)DB_tree.SelectedItem
```

Then everything I do to DummyObject is done to the original object. The equals operator for Objects acts more like assigning an alias than an equals operator.

Strange, that, though clearly common sense to OO programmers everywhere. If the equals operator worked the same way for doubles or ints it would be impossible to do math, now that I understand it, it is cleaning up a lot of my code.